# How to write a fibonacci codes in objective c?

Tags: objective-c

I want to display fibonacci numbers from a given number. For example the input number is 100, then display all fibonacci sequence of numbers.

Comment: First: what have you tried, second: what does *"then display all fibonacci sequence of numbers"* even mean? State ***clearly*** what you have tried so far, what the expected output for given input is and why and in what way **your current solution** does not work yet.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use this method to display fibonacci series from a given number.

```
 - (void) displayFibonacciNumbers:(int) n {
        NSMutableArray *fibSeries = [NSMutableArray new];
        int total = 0;
        int prev = 1;        
        for (int x=1; x<n; x++){
            total = total + prev;
            prev = total - prev;   
            [fibSeries addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:total]];
        }
        NSLog(@"Fibonacci numbers are: %@", fibSeries);
    }
```

Comment: This works good Thanks

Comment: Nice to help dude :)

Comment: The logic is not correct  if we start from 0, generally fibonacci start from 0 like  0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5,